# Why android returns Editable instead of String?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Even after setting `EditText` type to date or number etc., I need to convert the output of `getText()` to `String` first then to respective `Date` or `Integer`.

So, `Editable` does not seem any better than mere `String`, so why doesn't Android just return the `String`?

Comment: Simply why does EditText.getText() return Editable instead of String? We anyway convert Editable to String. Is there any use-case where we need to directly work with Editable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html) `String` is immutable. `Editable` [however](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html) allows its markup and content to be changed.

The reason `EditText` returns an `Editable` is likely for your ease - so you can edit the text, and set it again.